# NSURLConnection not calling connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

The is my code

```
theDownloadConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

and it is calling these NSURLConnection delegate methods

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

But it is not calling

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
                                                 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
                                         totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
```

This method of NSURLConnection delegate calls when I do this

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I dont understand why this is happening?

Comment: @EdwinIskandar I am experiencing the same issue, but I am definitely using an HTTP POST (with file upload).  Do you know what other expectations need to be met for NSURLConnection to call the `didSendBodyData` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didSendBodyData is only called when the request has a body containing message data like in  POST request. You are most likely executing a GET.

From the apple docs:

> connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
>   Sent as the body (message data) of a request is transmitted (such as
>   in an http POST request).

Comment: Are you sure. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score -1):

That's because its defined in *NSURLConnectionDataDelegate* and you are setting *NSURLConnection*
delegate.